# Как добавить в значения мапы массив стрингов?

Tags: golang

Хочу сделать map, где ключи - string, а значения - массив string.
x := make(map[string]string[]) -  не работает

Answer (score 1):

```
x := make(map[string][]string)
x["k1"] = []string{"v1", "v2"}
x["k2"] = []string{"v3", "v4"}
fmt.Println(x)
```

Comment: Он конечно спрашивал про массивы, но подразумевал скорее всего именно слайсы